# How to approach test automation of Graphs and Charts? i.e., elements made of <CANVAS> <SVG> tags

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, webdriver.io

In my project, we have a module called Reporting which covers graphs and charts.

It's basically a dashboard on the homepage of the website with multiple graphs and charts (after inspecting them they are seen to be made of <CANVAS & <SVG tags

They are representing Data from a DataSource.

Manual Test Cases defined are validating that the data represented by the graphs and charts are correct in 2 areas.

1. Quantification - Value represented in graph and chart
2. Quality - visual design of chart and graph

How to approach test automation of such test cases? Can we achieve 100% automation in such modules?

Comment: I would suggest two improvements to the question: 1 - Explain what do you mean by "100% automation". 2 - Explain what your program does, what risks are you investigating, etc - on top of the tools and libraries that you use to build the program (already explained). Knowing the *purpose* of your program may help to understand how to better investigate it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer, by 100% automation I meant will it be feasible to automate all manual test cases that were written for testing Graphs and Chart? I want to write a test automation code that will match datasets in database with its current depiction in the chart/graph. My program should login to website, simultaneously connect with a database in background, program should then start clicking on buttons that generate or display charts and graph and then match what is displayed with what exists in database. @JoãoFarias

Comment: Going a bit ahead, will it be feasible for any automation tool to analyze the display quality of graphs and charts?

Answer (score 0):

In the following video you can see James Bach testing and explaining the testing (including the usage of tools) of canvas-based web applications.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noKBIEtEGcs

[image]

You can see how to generate complex and edge-case data setups that may help to uncover subtle bugs.